# Why am I getting this routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whenever I use `job_medium_path` I receive this routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError Exception: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"media"}
```

However, when I use `rake routes` it clearly shows that there is a route for that path:

```
job_medium GET    /jobs/:job_id/media/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"media"}
```

Also, in the media controller the show action is defined.

Other routes and paths for this controller work perfectly, including:

```
job_media GET    /jobs/:job_id/media(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"media"}
new_job_medium GET    /jobs/:job_id/media/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"media"}
```

When I call the path on a page I use: `job_medium_path(@mediumable, @media)` and receive this error:

```
Routing Error
```

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"media", :job_id=>[all job info is here]}

Also here is the action:

```
def show
  @medium = @mediumable.media.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: do you have a show action defined on your media controller???

Comment: Yes I do, I just updated the question with it

Comment: So on your index page you have values for all your `@mediumable`'s? Also, in your `show` action, you would need to derive your `@mediumable` from the `job_id` in the path.

Comment: Yes @mediumable is defined as "job"

Comment: can you paste the routes definition?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the job and medium id, something like this:

```
job_medium_path(@job, @medium)
```

Comment: I am doing that when I call the path on a page and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Supossing `@job` and `@medium` exist, try this:

```
job_medium_path(job_id: @job.id, id: @medium.id)
```